# How can I decode this Malicious php code?

Tags: decryption, deobfuscation, php

I found this backdoor on a client's website.

https://github.com/baogiaphucthinh/Malicious-php/blob/main/1259da6sc.php (original file)

I have gotten rid of it and realise it's an obfuscated script but how can I deobfuscate it in order to get to the root of this matter and understand the motive behind this attack better?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like the main part is gzip compressed so try decompress to remove the obfuscation (at least the first layer)

Comment: thank you, i think he use TinyObfuscate, i saw the character is same same but i cant decode it

Comment: So what's underneath gzip layer? Either it's done (post an answer) or if not update the question with more info.

Comment: @JoeyDoe why do you think it is TinyObfuscate? I wrote TinyObfuscate and I can help you decode it.